# Uncertaintiy in the Angular Momentum Matrix

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, angular-momentum, wavefunction

So I have given the usual $L_x$, $L_y$ and $L_z$ operators in the matrix form for $l=1$, such as

$L_x = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}\quad$
$L_y = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{bmatrix}0 & -i & 0 \\ i & 0 & -i \\ 0 & i & 0 \end{bmatrix}\quad$
$L_z = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -1 \end{bmatrix}$

It's said that for $L_z=-1$ find the $\langle L_y \rangle$,$\langle L_y^2 \rangle$. If it was a normal operator or for a given wavefunction the equation is simple,

$$\langle Q(\hat{x},\hat{p}) \rangle = \int \Psi^*Q(x, -i\hbar\partial_x)\Psi dx$$

But in the question there's no wavefunction. I guess I am kind of lost for this case. What is the general operation for these cases?

Comment: You have $\ell$ and you have *m*. Why do you imagine there is no wavestate?

Comment: It may help to consider what basis you are using to represent the L matrices.

Comment: I kind of made progress and from my older notes I have found a way to solve the problem. However, I do not understand what is the point of choosing $L_z=-1$ and how it effects $L_y$ ?